# Writing IF THEN string calculation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else

I am attempting to calculate a text field in my attribute table based on a number code given in a different column

[image]

For example, any number under the "LU_1" column that is '510' will be given the name 'park' under the "UseName_1" column. I would like to use the Python 3 expression type.

Comment: What have you tried?  What research have you done?  I would suggest doing an internet search for Python `if` statements.  If you can't figure it out from there, and from ESRI's documentation, update your post here, to include the code that you tried and what is does/doesn't do wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest method is to use a dictionary [`.get()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) lookup with or without a default value:

Expression:

```
luname.get(!LU_1!)
```

Expression with a default value:

```
luname.get(!LU_1!, "Some default name text")
```

Code Block:

```
luname = {
    510: "park",
    700: "not a park",
    123: "something else"
}
```

[image]